# Help with Inputs using scanner

Tags: java, exception, input, java.util.scanner

```
public int Remove(int i, Briefcase c[], String[] m) {

        int nChoice = 0;
        boolean inputisok = false;

        while (inputisok == false) {
            System.out.print("\tPlease remove " + i + " cases: ");
            nChoice = input.nextInt();
            if (c[nChoice] == null || nChoice < 0 && nChoice >= c.length) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("\tInvalid Input please Try again\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\tI'm " + m[nChoice]
                        + " You just removed case # " + nChoice);
                System.out.println("\t|" + nChoice + "| contains $"
                        + c[nChoice].getAmount() + "\n");
                inputisok = true;
            }
        }
        return nChoice;
    }
```

my problem here is that when I enter a letter and a -negative number, or a number that is higher than 27, I always get an exception error, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line is incorrect:

```
if (c[nChoice] == null || nChoice < 0 && nChoice >= c.length) {
```

You want to change it like so:

```
if (nChoice < 0 || nChoice >= c.length || c[nChoice] == null) {
```

There are two changes: (1) the `&&` became a `||`; (2) the clauses have been reordered.

(1) The `&&` is wrong as `nChoice < 0 && nChoice >= c.length` always evaluates to `false`, since `nChoice` can't be simultaneously less than zero and greater than `c.length` (Thanks, @Aleks G!)

(2) In your original version you try to access `c[nChoice]` before making sure `nChoice` is within the bounds of `c`. If it isn't, this'll result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` instead of printing out "Invalid Input".

[Short-circuit evaluation](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=65) is the reason the ordering of clauses matters.

Lastly, before reading from `input`, you could call [`hasNextInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) to make sure that the next token can be interpreted as a valid integer.

Comment: I don't think the first part would ever evaluate to true: `c.length` will always be greater than or equal to 0; therefore the first part of this `if` statement essentially means `if(cChoice < 0 && cChoice >=0)` - this will always be `false`.  I think what he probably needs is `if(nChoice < 0 || nChoice >= c.length || c[nChoice] == null)`

Comment: Alright done, the only error thing now is when I input a negative number and a letter, what more?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [hasNextInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28int%29) method:

```
public int Remove(int i, Briefcase c[], String[] m) {

    boolean isNextIntCorrect = false;
    int enteredInt;

    while(!isNextIntCorrect){
        System.out.println("\tPlease remove " + i + " cases: ");
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(input.next());
        if(inputScanner.hasNextInt()){
            enteredInt = inputScanner.nextInt();
            isNextIntCorrect = enteredInt >= 0 && enteredInt < c.length 
                && enteredInt < m.length)
        }
        inputScanner.close();

        if(!isNextIntCorrect){
            System.out.println("\tInvalid Input please Try again\n");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\tI'm " + m[enteredInt]
                    + " You just removed case # " + enteredInt);
    System.out.println("\t|" + enteredInt+ "| contains $"
                    + c[enteredInt].getAmount() + "\n");
}
```

This way you are sure of dealing with a *correct* int!